How to pull out the most similar words in DRF and Postgres?
My backend server consists of drf and postgres.
What I want to do is, if any keyword comes from the client, the result is the B field value in the A table that is most similar to it.
Therefore I wanted to use trigram_similar and it worked, but I can't use pg_trgm anymore because the service has to support Korean.
How do I resolve this?
